# Node vs AnchorNode in ARCore

Tags: android, arcore

what is the difference between Node and AnchorNode in ArCore?
I found absolutely no difference between them.

```
        val node = Node()
        node.renderable = it
        scene.addChild(node)
        node.worldPosition = Vector3(x, y, z)

        val node = AnchorNode()
        node.renderable = it
        scene.addChild(node)
        node.worldPosition = Vector3(x, y, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

An AnchorNode is a node which is associated with an ARCore anchor. An AnchorNode inherits many of its methods from the Node class and can be used in the same way as a node as you have seen.

From the documentation:

**Node**

> A Node represents a transformation within the scene graph's hierarchy. It can contain a renderable for the rendering engine to render.
>
> Each node can have an arbitrary number of child nodes and one parent. The parent may be another node, or the scene.

**Anchor node**

> Node that is automatically positioned in world space based on an ARCore Anchor.
>
> When the Anchor isn't tracking, all children of this node are disabled.